# Can't get BannerAds for Admob to display in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, admob, ionic4, banner-ads

I followed a [guide](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-implement-admob-free-native-plugin-in-latest-ionic-4-applications-more-efficiently/) to show banner ads in my application. I followed the guide, but for whatever reason the banner ads don't show up.

My application is a bit different than the one presented since my application uses tabs. I tried putting the code in the guide that was meant for home in my tabs page (the page that controls/displays the tabs within my app). Is this not the right place?? Or do I need to have the code for home in all of my individual tab pages?

`admob.service`

```js
  BannerAd() {
    let bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      // isTesting: true, // Remove in production
      autoShow: true,
      id: "ca-app-pub-1234978941/134134317"
    };
    this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

    this.admobFree.banner.prepare().then(() => {
      // success
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }
```

I removed `isTesting: true,` from the code since I figured I woulnd't need it.

Am I missing something? Or is the guide just outdated and requires more code for this?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the console? Or an error alert based on the try/catch statement?

Comment: I believe that ads are only able to be shown when you're running an a device itself or when emulating android. I tried to do ionic serve but it gives an error that says, ``` Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator ``` . I'm unsure of how to check for errors on a device itself.

Comment: I tried to do ionic serve --devapp I get the error 

```"Native: tried calling AdMobFree.config, but the AdMobFree plugin is not installed."
"Install the AdMobFree plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free'" ``` However,  cordova-plugin-admob is installed

Comment: So I used the developer tools on chrome to connect my device to check the console but no errors are showing up. Even when testing with isTesting nothing shows up still. I decided to try and put my code in just my tabs.ts and call it there but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Your application has to be the release version for ads to display properly. It takes a day or so for the ads to display.